# Prevent Service Sleeping Machine

Tags: windows, power, kernel, asus-laptop

I have an Asus G15 (GA503QS), and on this machine I have a service, the Asus Optimisation Service.

As far as I'm aware, this service, amongst other things, prevents my battery from charging above 60% so that I can extend its longevity.

However, I've found that this service appears to be bugged and frequently sends my computer to sleep whilst I'm playing games (god knows why, I've checked and the temperatures are well within safe ranges).

I know this because the event viewer has these two entries:

First:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
  <EventID>187</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>243</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000400000000404</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-03-07T02:02:59.2567029Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>12414</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4728" ThreadID="24452" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-V8PMSBK</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="ApiCallerNameLength">141</Data> 
  <Data Name="ApiCallerName">\Device\HarddiskVolume6\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\asussci2.inf_amd64_2346917970a59cb8\ASUSOptimization\AsusOptimization.exe</Data> 
  <Data Name="SystemAction">3</Data> 
  <Data Name="LightestSystemState">2</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Then almost immediately:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
  <EventID>42</EventID> 
  <Version>3</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>64</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000404</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-03-07T02:03:01.0699544Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>12415</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="15216" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-V8PMSBK</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="TargetState">5</Data> 
  <Data Name="EffectiveState">5</Data> 
  <Data Name="Reason">4</Data> 
  <Data Name="Flags">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="TransitionsToOn">5</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

So, my question is thus: I want to keep this service largely intact but I want to prevent it issuing call to the kernel to sleep my machine.

I know how I'd approach this on Linux but on Windows I have no idea... And I'm stuck with Windows until Nvidia sort out the mess that is the 3000 series mobile GPU driver for Linux.

Any ideas?

Comment: Windows 10.  Start, Settings, System, Power and Sleep:  Set Sleep, when Plugged in, to Never.  That stops my Windows 10 computers from sleeping when plugged in (two laptops, one desktop).

Comment: Yeah, I've already got that, won't stop an application/service sending the sleep request

Comment: Must be a bug in the ASUS app.

Comment: Kill the service.  Disable.  Life is too short.

Answer (score 0):

It has been said that restarting the ASUS Optimization Service helps avoid the problem.

You could set up a scheduled task to restart the service. It can run a `.bat`
file that will do `net stop <service-name>`.

If this doesn't help, just disable the service by using the Services applet.
You could also file a bug-report with ASUS.

Comment: Aye, I have filed a bug report with Asus... Is there really no way to blacklist an executable from sending specific API calls?

Comment: There is no such feature, especially for a system service. If restarting the service doesn't help, disabling, or setting its startup to Manual, is only left.